# Touch Detected on UIImageView Background

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UIImageView that loads several different pictures of different sizes and fills the remaining area of the UIImageView with a black background. I am trying to find a way that tapping anywhere on the black background, but not on the image, will hide the UIImageView. Is there anyway to do this?

Edit:

[image]

This is the layout of the screen. I'm trying to make it so tapping anywhere in the black area will hide the big image and just show the remaining things in the background to look like this:

[image]

The big image and black background are all in one UIImageView. I just need a way to detect a tap in the black area and then I can set imageview.hidden = true

Comment: please provide your **code**

Comment: You need to provide more details in your question, as otherwise it is likely to be closed as too broad and/or not enough information to be able to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class of type `UIViewController` that would implement the functionality. It looks like you are using a `UICollectionView`, but it should still work.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let imageView = UIImageView()
    var gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: imageView, action: #selector(ViewController.gestureActivated))
        gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        gesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func gestureActivated() {
        let tap = gesture.location(in: imageView)

        if let image = imageView.image?.accessibilityFrame {
            if !image.contains(tap) {
                imageView.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In the `viewDidLoad` I give the image view a `UIGestureRecognizer` that is activated when one finger is used to tap it once. When the tap is made, the `gestureActivated` function is called.

A constant is then created with the location of the tap in the image view.

After you get the position of the tap, we check to see if it was on the image. If not, then we hide the image view.

Comment: My imageview contains the black background as well as the image itself and I want the gesture to only be recognized when tapping the black background but not when tapping the image

Comment: Have you confirmed that the action gets fired when you select the image?

Comment: It appears that gestureActivated() is never being called. Here is my class's code: http://pastebin.com/wBm0FVfK